# Android Studio module that depends on another module's tests

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I'm trying to get the Gradle Java plugin to execute jUnit tests that exist in an Android project. My solution was to create a second module that applies the Java plugin, and set the test sourceSet to the app module's src/test directory.

*test-module's build.gradle:*

```
apply plugin: 'java'
...
dependencies {
    ...
    testCompile project(':app-module')
}
sourceSets {
    test {
        java.srcDirs += ["${appDir}/src/test/java"]
    }
}
```

This works fine from the command line, but Android Studio refuses to import a project that has source sets outside the submodule. It throws the error: `Can't register given path of type 'TEST' because it's out of content root.`

```
.
├── app-module
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── src
│       ├── main
│       └── test
├── test-module
│   └── build.gradle
├── build.gradle
└── settings.gradle
```

I tried configuring this from the parent build.gradle, but that didn't change anything. I can add app-module as a testCompile project dependency in test-module, but that doesn't cause test-module to add app-module's tests.

Any ideas for getting test-module to run app-module's tests without provoking Android Studio's limitation about remote source sets?

Comment: I ended up just keeping the tests in the java plugin module's source tree. Not the way I like it, but it works.

Comment: Any news? I want to do the same thing.

Comment: Last time I tried, Studio still didn't like it. Haven't tried the latest update though.